# Change ID(INT) to ID(UUID)

Tags: sql-server

In the existing database I would like to change the existing ID as int on UUID

As you can see below, the column is now the main key with the CLUSTERED index

Sample table creation code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUsers](
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LoginName] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How to solve the problem in a quick way for many tables?

The table can have many rows so I'm wondering how to do the index. In general, you should not create an index on UUID.

EDIT:

An example of another referencing table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUsersDist](
    [UserDistID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUsersDist] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserDistID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: *"In general, you should not create an index on UUID."* Why do you say that? It's not a good idea to created a **Clustered** Index on a `uniqueidentifier` that doesn't have an sequential value, but otherwise, it's fine. Also, an `int` and a `uniqueidentifier` are completely different types of values. What value for the `uniqueidentifier` would you expect fior the values `1`, `17`, and `367283`?

Comment: Are any other foreign keys pointing to the column `UserID` as well? If so, changing to a `uniqueidentifier` is going to be a huge head ache for maintaining referential integrity; you'll basically need to rebuild the entire database.

Comment: @Larnu There are references from other tables. I have to rebuild the base again but it is clean. The changed version will be used from scratch. I am looking for a way to quickly rebuild the file generating the entire empty table

Comment: @Larnu I mean I showed one table here and I would like to replace it with UUID in each ID table.

Comment: @Larnu I've added an example of another table that references the previous one

Comment: What is expected number of rows in a table? Maybe you can change data type from **int** (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) to **bigint** (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to:

1. Begin a transaction
2. Drop the `PRIMARY KEY` on your original table.
3. Add a new column with the `uniqueidentifier` data type.
4. Update the new column with new `UUID` values.
5. Set the new column as `NOT NULL` (needed for the `PRIMARY KEY`).
6. Drop the original `INT` column.
7. Rename the new `UUID` column to match the original `INT` column (optional).
8. Add a new `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.
9. Commit transaction.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    UserID INT IDENTITY,
    Data INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID))

INSERT INTO Test (Data)
VALUES (10), (20)


BEGIN TRANSACTION

    ALTER TABLE Test DROP PK_Test

    ALTER TABLE Test ADD UUID uniqueidentifier

    UPDATE Test SET UUID = NEWID()

    ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN UUID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL

    ALTER TABLE Test DROP COLUMN UserID

    EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Test.UUID', 'UserID', 'COLUMN'

    ALTER TABLE Test ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY (UserID)

COMMIT
```

Note that the example is missing the proper error handling. Additionally, if you have foreign keys you will have to drop them at the beginning and recreate them at the end but ***beware of the new data type***.

Comment: If the OP wants a Clustered primary key, like they have already, I recommend `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` as the default value; otherwise the pages will need to keep getting ordered, and that gets expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create a new table, insert the old values, follow suit for every table, and then drop your old table and rename the new. Messy, but changing the data type of a PK is always messy.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblUsers_New (UserID uniqueidentifier
                                   DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() NOT NULL,
                               OldUserID int NULL, --incase you'll keep it, as new user won't have a new "old" ID
                               LastName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
                               LoginName nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
                               RoleID int,         --Is that going to be a GUID too?
                               CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUsers]
                                   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC));

INSERT INTO tblUsers_New (OldUserID,LastName,LoginName,RoleID)
SELECT UserID,
       LastName,
       LoginName,
       RoleID
FROM dbo.tblUsers
ORDER BY UserID ASC;

/* Repeat process for all of your other tables, maintaining referencial integrity.
   Start dropping the old tables, again, maintaining referential integrity
   and renaming the new tables.
*/

DROP TABLE dbo.tbl_users;
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.tblUsers_New', N'tblUsers';  

/* Then finally set up the Foreign key constraints.*/
```

This, of course, is only a vague idea on how to do it, as we only have a vague idea of your data.

Comment: What to do with this error? `Table 'dbo.tblUsers' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.` Previously I had `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Comment: Maybe I'll start with another question to get back to it. Do I need to assign `DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to wherever I use the `uniqueidentifier` (master key and foreign key)? When I have an `ID` as `INT`, by default I can specify `-1` for a foreign key during `INSERT`. Now, in the case of `UUID`, I can not add anything while using `INSERT`

Comment: Why were you trying to insert a value for a column that was an `IDENTITY` in the first place? The idea of an `IDENTITY` is that SQL Server handles creating the value of the "ID". That is exactly what I've done here. Otherwise where is the value of your `uniqueindentier` coming from, and how are you ensuring it's sequential (as you're putting a Clustered index on it)?